# wpcept: command not found

Tags: wordpress, automated-tests, codeception

I am trying to get `Codeception` running on `localhost` for `WordPress`, using [this official documentation](http://codeception.com/for/wordpress).

I was able to complete the first step (Install). On second step (Setup) when I run the following command

`wpcept bootstrap`

I am getting this error.

```
wpcept: command not found
```

Note:-

- I tried following the steps on a fresh install of WP, but still the same error.
- I tried re-running the commands in step one (Install) and composer showed the typical `Nothing to install or update` message.
- Just to rule out my local machine mis-configuration possibility, I tried following the [Joomla! documentation](http://codeception.com/for/joomla) on a local Joomla! install, and everything worked just fine!

Comment: Try to run vendor/bin/wpcept

Comment: @Naktibalda Cool!!! I tried running `vendor/bin/wpcept bootstrap` from my site root, and it worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little out of date. With the latest version of WP Browser for CodeCeption, the

```
wpcept
```

command has been depreciated in favor of the regular

```
codecept
```

command. If that doesn't work try:

```
  vendor/bin/codecept
```

It comes with a new installer as well. If you want to setup CodeCeption for WordPress on Ubuntu (cloud or local) here is an example:

[WordPress-BDD.com](https://wordpress-bdd.com/bdd-wp-aws/)